# jQuery - On Click replace iFrame content with new content

Tags: jquery, vimeo

Trying to figure out the best way to do this. I have a main video player pulling in a video from Vimeo. Underneath this main player is thumbnails of other videos. When the user clicks on a thumbnail I want it to make that thumbnail video take the place of the main video.

Vimeo embeds are all iFrame based. I'm not sure if I should be replacing the whole iFrame, or just the URL etc. Also the size difference between the main on and the thumbnail; not sure if that will get carried across automatically or the Vimeo code will be clever enough to resize. And can the Jquery click override the click the thumbnail usually expects to play the small video?

HTML

```
<div class="blogPlayer">
    <iframe src="#" width="528" height="297" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<ul class="blogThumbnails>
    <li><iframe src="#" width="160" height="90" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>
    <li><iframe src="#" width="160" height="90" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>
    <li><iframe src="#" width="160" height="90" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>
</ul>
```

This jQuery is completely untested and done on the spot, but was thinking something along the lines of...

```
$('.blogThumbnails li').click(function(){
   var video = $(this).html();
   $('.blogPlayer').replaceWith('video');
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just replace the src file instead of replacing the whole iframe. If you are replacing the whole iframe then you'll need to adjust the attribute of the clicked list.

This is what I have in mind:

```
<div>
      <iframe src="#" id="blogPlayer" width="528" height="297" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

$('.blogThumbnails li').click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr('src');
   $('#blogPlayer).attr('src', url);
   return false;
})
```

If you go with the other route you'll need to adjust the width and height:

```
$('.blogThumbnails li').click(function(){
   var video = $(this).html();
   $('.blogPlayer')
          .replaceWith(video)
          .attr({
                  width: '528',
                  height: '297'
          });
   return false;
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do `.replaceWith(video)` since `video` is a variable?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `.attr({ width: '528', height: '297'})`? Not to mention if you did use your `style`, you have a `,` after your `;`.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I did it on the fly without really thinking it through! I should rewrite the codes in an editor next time.

Comment: @nolabel - Haha, no worries. I do the same.  I have to look over it like 10 times and there's always something I missed.

Comment: Thanks, I think your idea of just replacing the URL is best, however there are 2 points. Firstly, how can my click override the Vimeo player thumbnail just playing the actually clip? Secondly, when the page has loaded the iframe actually has a few src attributes for the Flash player etc, how could I be sure it's getting the correct src attribute?

Comment: Hi Yammi, "return false;" will override Vimeo default behavior. I have updated the codes.

As for your second question, is the attributes part of the src? If so it should be included. If it is not, you may want to create another question for this since it is moving away from the original question.

Comment: To make it short, you can change the attributes by adding it to, e.g., .attr({ x: 'yes', b: '55' })